# Ruby - Imprimindo zero como casa decimal

Tags: ruby

Estou aprendendo a programar em Ruby, e para ir treinando, uso o Uri Online Judge, onde resolvo exercícios que são apresentados, faço o código em alguma linguagem que a plataforma aceite (nesse caso o Ruby) e depois envio para o sistema, mas a saída tem que ser exatamente igual a que é apresentado, como por exemplo, exibir duas casas decimais (dois números após o ponto), não pode ser nem mais nem menos.

Estou com dificuldade em fazer o Ruby exibir os zeros da casa decimal.

Como por exemplo o numero 1051 (estou com dificuldades em outros exercícios também, mas esse foi o mais recente), o código é:

```
a = 1000 * (8/100.0)
b = 1500 * (18/100.0)
s = gets.to_f
if s >= 0 and s <= 2000
    puts "Isento"
elsif s > 2000 and s <= 3000
    s -= 2000
    s *= 8/100.0
    puts "R$ #{s.round 2}\n"
elsif s > 3000 and s <= 4500
    s -= 3000
    s *= 18/100.0
    s += a
    puts "R$ #{s.round 2}\n"
elsif s > 4500
    s -= 4500
    s *= 28/100.0
    s += a + b
    puts "R$ #{s.round 2}\n"
end
```

Ele deve exibir duas casa decimais, mas quando a saída iria/deve apresentar casas decimais com "0", ele não exibe. Já somei a variável com 0.001 mas mesmo assim, exibe apenas 1 casa decimal em caso de zeros.

Como posso resolver isso, ou é um bug do próprio Ruby?

> exemplo de saída apresentado pelo URI:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode a saída do ponto flutuante, tente:

```
puts "R$ %0.02f\n" % s.round(2)
```

ao invés de

```
puts "R$ #{s.round 2}\n"
```

Resultado pra mim foi ok, se eu entendi bem sua pergunta:

```
4520.00
R$ 355.60
```

Boa sorte.
EDIT: [mais algumas dicas de formatação](http://www.blackbytes.info/2012/01/ruby-string-formatting/)

Comment: deu certo.. não sabia que tinha essa forma de se imprimir em Ruby, conhecia epenas a que eu apresentei e `puts "R$ " + s.to_s`

Comment: @n3h heheh, pois eh. Essa forma lembro que usava muito no C, bem útil para esses caso também. Bons estudos.

Comment: sim, eu também fiz os mesmos exercícios em C, e é bem parecido mesmo (`printf("%.2f", s);`). obrigado pela orientação..